# Contar quantidade de elemento de um array de uma página

Tags: php

Olá, boa tarde. Como eu posso fazer um loop foreach ou um preg_match_all para contar a quantidade em que o elemento **appid** se repete em uma página ?

Tentei desta maneira **e** consegui:

```
    function get_Jogos() {
$array = [ ["appid" => 291550,"name" => "Brawlhalla"], ["appid" => 000000,"name" => "Teste"], ["appid" => 000023,"name" => "Teste2"], ];    
foreach($array as $arr) 
    if (array_key_exists("appid", $arr))
    echo $jogos =  $arr["name"] . "<br>";
}

get_Jogos();
```

***Nova dúvida:***

> Como verificar a existência da string "appid" numa página depois de um
>   cURL e assim fazer a listagem dos nomes dos "jogos" ?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/games/?tab=all");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Sabrina, tente isso: `$count = count(array_keys($array, 'appid', true));` e depois: `echo $count;` para ver se exibe o resultado.

Comment: É em PHP ou JavaScript!?

Comment: Tentei desta forma: `$array = [
["appid" => 291550,"name" => "Brawlhalla"],
["appid" => 000000,"name" => "Teste"],
];

$count = count(array_keys($array, 'appid', true));
echo $count;` O retorno é: 0. É em php

Comment: Ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [ ["appid" => 291550,"name" => "Brawlhalla"], ["appid" => 000000,"name" => "Teste"], ];

$count = 0;

foreach($array as $arr)
    if (array_key_exists("appid", $arr))
        $count++;

echo $count;
```

Fazendo um `foreach` na variável `$array`, cada `$arr` que a função retornar será uma `subarray` da `array` principal. Então basta usar a função `array_key_exists()` passando o elemento que deseja procurar, que no caso é `appid` e passando a `array` em que deseja verificar, no caso são as `$arr`, se encontrar só incrementar no contador, `$count`.

Comment: Estou com uma nova dúvida, irei editar o tópico. Se puder me ajudar, ficarei mais grata ainda.

Comment: Seria melhor deixar a pergunta anterior e realizar uma nova no stack

Comment: Desculpa, queria poupar um novo tópico com um "problema" similar